# Запрос в базу MySQL. Выборка c условием по дате

Tags: php, mysql

Здравствуйте, скажите пожалуйста, возможно ли сделать запрос в базу такого вида:

выбрать все записи с датой меньше заданной - строка вида: "03.04.14 14:42"

Сейчас делаю запрос и потом условие:

```
$date = "03.04.14 14:42";
$query = "SELECT
            *,
            DATE_FORMAT(
              CONVERT_TZ(created,'+00:00','+04:00'),
              '%d.%m.%y %H:%i'
            ) as date_f
          FROM
            items
          ORDER BY
            created DESC";
$result = mysql_query($query); 

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
  $i++;
  if ($i <= 500 AND $row['date_f'] <= $date){
    echo $row['date_f']."<br />";
  }
}
```

Но дело в том что результат выполнения условия выводит **только даты за текущий месяц:**

```
03.04.14 14:42
03.04.14 13:36
03.04.14 13:29
03.04.14 09:55
03.04.14 08:49
02.04.14 15:52
02.04.14 13:54
02.04.14 13:42
02.04.14 12:28
02.04.14 12:10
02.04.14 11:22
02.04.14 11:12
02.04.14 11:04
02.04.14 10:59
```

**Как мне сделать SQL-запрос или условие чтобы в результате отображались ВСЕ даты меньше исходной?**

Comment: 1) Почему бы сразу не делать запрос с условием WHERE на нужный диапазон дат?
2) Я вижу ограничения через PHP код, вы пробовали проверить сам запрос, выдает ли он нужный диапазон? 
3) Явная ошибка - это сравнение дат как строк, когда формат %d.%m.%y этого не предоставляет. Если хотите корректного сравнения, то используйте %y.%m.%d %H:%i

Comment: 3) исходная дата - строка, она изначально не может быть датой

Comment: 2) 4700 строк без условия

Comment: 1)А как сделать запрос? Как указать начальную дату? например: 2 месяца назад - исходная дата

Comment: 1) Насколько я понимаю у вас в базе datetime, тогда и обращайтесь напрямую: SELECT *, created as date_f  FROM items WHERE created < '03.04.14 14:42:00' ORDER BY created DESC

2) Ну просто удостоверится, что приходят даты и другие.

3) У Вас есть такое условие $row['date_f'] <= $date. Вы я так понимаю думаете, что например "31.01.10 14:42" <= "03.04.14 14:42" выдаст true, но строки сравниваются в лексиграфическом формате, поэтому 3>0 и выдаст false. Это не то, что вы хотите, поэтому обычно даты либо указывают как %y.%m.%d %H:%i, котрое совпадает с лексиграфическим, либо переводят в timestamp.

Answer (score 1):

Расширение mysql признано устаревшим и исключено из PHP 7. При формировании выборки лучше ориентироваться на расширения mysqli или PDO.

Для того, чтобы отфильтровать дату на уровне SQL-запроса следует создать условие `create < '2014-04-03 14:42:00'`

```
<?php
  try {
    $pdo = new PDO(
      'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test',
      'root',
      '',
      [PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION]);

    $date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d.m.y H:i', "03.04.14 14:42");

    $query = "SELECT
                *
              FROM
                history
              WHERE
                created < :created
              ORDER BY
                created DESC";
    $itm = $pdo->prepare($query);
    $itm->execute(['created' => $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')]);

    while($item = $itm->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
      $date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $item['created']);
      echo $date->format('d.m.Y H:i')."<br />";
    }
  } catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo "Ошибка выполнения запроса: " . $e->getMessage();
  }
```

В примере был задействован предопределенный класс `DateTime::createFromFormat` для форматирования строки с датой и временем.

Comment: доброго времени у меня похожая проблема - не стал создавать вопрос тут и так много подобного у меня не работает такое: $tmp = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM stactions WHERE STR_TO_DATE (fdate, '%Y-%m=%d') <= STR_TO_DATE ('$datenow', '%Y-%m=%d') AND STR_TO_DATE (tohda, '%Y-%m=%d') <= STR_TO_DATE ('$datenow', '%Y-%m=%d')");

Comment: @dantelol возникает ошибка или нарушение в логике работы скрипта?

Comment: нет ошибок нету) он просто возвращает пустой результат как будто нет совпадений хотя там как минимум 2 строки со значениями 2016-11-11 и 2016-10-8, а он просто пустой результат дает

Comment: @dantelol Погодите, у вас календарные данные? 2016-11-11 и 2016-10-8? Тогда вам вообще не надо STR_TO_DATE() сравнивайте их прямо так.

Comment: к сожалению и без STR_TO_DATE не работает\

Comment: Данные да календарные в таблице тип поля date